# Working on backend with Nuxt frontend url paths

Tags: laravel, rest, nuxt.js, url-routing

I have a project, using Nuxt 2 as frontend and Php-Laravel as backend app. The app have multiple language on each side also using localized routes in Nuxt + i18n.

We're sending some notification emails on backend managed by cron jobs, some emails contains a links to directed to front end.

But there is too many options due to localized routes and it is hard to manage.

For example, there is a page on frontend

```
en/account/payments/12345/invoice
tr/hesap/ödemeler/12345/fatura
es/cuenta/pagos/12345/factura
fr/compte/paiements/12345/facture
it/account/pagamenti/12345/fattura
```

How can i manage that?

I've tried a create server middleware on Nuxt to create these routes and to work act rest api server only return paths as json, but i can't access vue-router on server middleware.

Could you suggest me a solution?

Comment: The locale is in the path, not a subdomain? Then you could use a dynamic page. If you want all of your pages to be i18n'ed, I guess that you need to make them all dynamic. That way, you can make the check on the client side at least.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Locale is in the path, right, not a sub domain.

I don't understand what you mean "you need to make them all dynamic".

Comment: We're sending an email from backend in English, and email includes a link that "https://example.com/en/account/payments/12345/invoice"

Then, next email is sending from backend to different user the same content but in Espanol, and includes a link that "https://example.com/es/cuenta/pagos/54321/factura"

Comment: You need to have your path with dynamic nested routes, all of them: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing#dynamic-nested-routes